# unable to auto increment in foreach key as value

Tags: php

I am using a select group by query as i have duplicate value in the column and a foreach loop to generate each result for each increment. however, i got my result correctly but not the increment and i need to compare my result with (if statement) too.

```
$sqlr = mysql_query ("SELECT lati, COUNT(*) FROM upload GROUP BY lati HAVING COUNT(lati) > 1;"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlr)) 
{

    $countedlati = array($row['lati']);
    foreach ($countedlati as $key => $lativalue) {
         echo $key ."</br>".$lativalue ."</br>";
    }

}
```

the result

[image]

what i want is this result

```
0
1.3048
1
3.140583
```

And later compare the result in if statement

```
for( $i=$offset; $i<$end; $i++ )
{
   $data = $res[$i];

   if($data['latitude'] == $lativalue){
    $icon = "upload/yellow.png";
   }

}
```

Comment: `$countedlati = array($row['lati']);`  This is creating an array with just a single row.  It is unclear why you are doing this and why you have the `foreach` loop.  Also, you should be using the `mysqli` extension, not the `mysql` one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you do `$countedlati = array($row['lati']);` you define array with 1 element - that why you get the 0 each time.

You should add the element to one array and then iterate on him. Consider the following example:

```
$sqlr = mysql_query ("SELECT lati, COUNT(*) FROM upload GROUP BY lati HAVING COUNT(lati) > 1;"); 

$latis = array(); // init empty array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlr)) {   
    $latis[] = $row['lati']; // append the element to the array
}
```

Now you can do `foreach` loop as:

```
foreach($latis as $lati) {
   if($lati == $lativalue){
       $icon = "upload/yellow.png";
   }
}
```

Comment: i finally understand, after trying a few times. thank u so much dWinder